# How to generate coordinates of a circle in a list

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, nested-lists

I am trying to simulate particle diffusion and I need to generate their starting coordinates. They need to start in a circle with coordinates [x,y] in a list.
For example when the particles start the simulation in a square the coords array looks like this:

[[2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 3]]

I am also attempting to have the start position of the particles roughly in the centre of the grid. For example the above coordinates are the start positions in a 5x5 grid

Does anyone have any suggestions how to generate coordinates in a circle (not just coordinates on the circumference, filled in)

To generate the points in a square I use the code below:

class grid():

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    
    self.grid = np.zeros((x,y))
    self.list_of_atoms=[]
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    
def initiate_atoms_in_square(self,quantity):
    """initiate a square of atoms roughly in the centre of the grid space """
    self.side_length = int(math.sqrt(quantity))
    self.start = int(self.x/2 + ((self.x**2)/2))
    lower_x = int(self.x/2)
    upper_x = int(self.x/2+self.side_length)
    lower_y = int(self.y/2)
    upper_y = int(self.y/2+self.side_length)
      
    coords=[]
    for i in range(lower_x,upper_x):
        for j in range(lower_y,upper_y):
            coords.append([i,j])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which calculates an array of squared distances from the centre point and then gets the indices of the closest n points -- by sorting a list of `(squared_distance, indices)` tuples where `indices` is itself a tuple of indices (as returned by `np.ndindex`) -- and sets the `self.grid` array values to 1 at those points.  (There is some explicit looping, so maybe a more efficient solution exists.)

Note that I have put the grid as `(y, x)` so that y relates to the rows, because it is more confusing the other way round.

It also creates a list of indices in `self.list_of_atoms`.  (Each element of the list is a tuple of indices.)

```
import numpy as np

class Grid():
    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.grid = np.zeros((y,x), dtype=np.int)
        self.list_of_atoms=[]
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def initiate_atoms_in_circle(self, quantity, centrex=None, centrey=None):
        if centrex == None:
            centrex = self.x / 2
        if centrey == None:
            centrey = self.y / 2

        xvals, yvals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(self.x), np.arange(self.y))
        dist2 = (xvals - centrex) ** 2 + (yvals - centrey) ** 2
        dist2_and_pos = [(dist2[indices], indices) for indices in np.ndindex(dist2.shape)]
        dist2_and_pos.sort()

        for _, indices in dist2_and_pos[:quantity]:
            self.grid[indices] = 1
            self.list_of_atoms.append(indices)

        self.list_of_atoms.sort()
            
g = Grid(20, 15)
g.initiate_atoms_in_circle(100)
print(g.grid)
print("Total atoms:", np.sum(g.grid))
print("Length of indices list:", len(g.list_of_atoms))
print("Start of indices list:", g.list_of_atoms[:5])
```

This gives:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
Total atoms: 100
Length of indices list: 100
Start of indices list: [(2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (3, 7), (3, 8)]
```

Comment: I am getting an error now when i use these coordinates which i think comes from your code outputting at list of tuples. Do you have any suggestions to convert to a list of lists?

Comment: @Tom `[list(tpl) for tpl in mylist]` would make a list of lists from a list of tuples.

Comment: getting late with me I'm obviously being stupid. Ive put in  [list(tpl) for tpl in self.list_of_atoms] but I am still getting a list of tuples.

Comment: @Tom That won't modify the list, it's just an expression to create a new list - you'll have to assign it back to `self.list_of_atoms`

Comment: @Tom By the way, if you know you want a list of lists, you can always just change the `self.list_of_atoms.append(indices)` in my code to `self.list_of_atoms.append(list(indices))` rather than have to post-process the list afterwards.